# How to speed up VBA style replacement for multiple words within MS Word document?

Tags: vba, performance, ms-word

I've been trying some days ago with some variations of the following script in order to change the style of the words 
within the Array. The document has about 1200 pages and 8MB in size, but this seems to be heavier for MS Word.

The script below it seems to work faster than using `Selection.Find` but after 40 minutes I needed to stop the macro because
only 64 iterations (of 182) were executed.

Is there another way to enhance the execution speed of this macro? I even tried nested loop looking all words for each paragraph but was worst.

The macro finds each word of the array within the document and
if the word is bold and not italic applies StyleA
if the word is not bold and not italic applies StyleB
if the word is italic applies StyleC

Thanks for any help.

```
Sub ChangeStyles()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim Arr(1 To 182)
    Dim rng As Word.Range

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Arr=Array("Word1","Word2",..,"Word182",)

For i = 0 To UBound(Arr)
    Set rng = ActiveDocument.Content

    With rng.Find
        .ClearFormatting
        .Replacement.ClearFormatting
        .Text = Arr(i)
        .Execute
        If rng.Characters(1).Font.Bold = True And rng.Characters(1).Font.Italic = False Then
        .Replacement.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles("StyleA")
        ElseIf rng.Characters(1).Font.Bold = False And rng.Characters(1).Font.Italic = False Then
            .Replacement.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles("StyleB")
        ElseIf rng.Characters(1).Font.Italic = True Then
            .Replacement.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles("StyleC")
        End If
        .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    End With
    Debug.Print "word: " & i
Next


Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: The logic here is wrong - I think I've gone over this same basic thing, before. You have `Execute` twice in the loop, the second time with`ReplacAll`. This simply makes no sense. If you're going to go this route, rather than the one I suggested as being faster, then simply do `rng.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles("NameOfStyle")` in the `If...Else` instead of setting a `Replacement.Style` and trying to execute `Find` again. But I still say a Find/Replace for each formatting variation would be more efficient...

Comment: Hi Cindy. Sorry bother you. I've tested with your suggestion and it works but in actual file gets stuck. I'm not sure why. I understand that after ".Text(i)" in order to find the word is needed to send ". Execute" and after find it I inserted the if conditions to apply corresponding style. I understand that at this moment only one word was matched and in order to change the style to all instances I added "ReplaceAll”. How should be? And instead of what should I use "rng.Style=..."? Thanks again. The main reason why I continue testing is because of the slow performance.

Comment: @CindyMeister. Thanks for help so far. The change of styles works, but the speed execution is excessively slow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The logic in your code is wrong. Although you have set a replacement style you have not set any formatting for `Find` to find. As a result `.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll` will find all instances of `.Text = Arr(i)` and replace the style with whatever style has been set in the If statement from the first result.

As Cindy Meister pointed out in her comment, using mutiple iterations of find and replace for each word is likely to give the fastest results.

I have edited your code to show you how you can achieve this.

```
Sub ChangeStyles()
  Dim i As Long
  Dim Arr(1 To 182)

  Application.ScreenUpdating = False

  Arr=Array("Word1","Word2",..,"Word182",)

  For i = 0 To UBound(Arr)
    ReplaceStyle SearchText:=Arr(i), Bold:=True, Italic:=False, NewStyle:=ActiveDocument.Styles("StyleA")
    ReplaceStyle SearchText:=Arr(i), Bold:=False, Italic:=False, NewStyle:=ActiveDocument.Styles("StyleB")
    ReplaceStyle SearchText:=Arr(i), Bold:=False, Italic:=True, NewStyle:=ActiveDocument.Styles("StyleC")
  Next

  Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub

Sub ReplaceStyle(SearchText As String, Bold As Boolean, Italic As Boolean, NewStyle As style)
  Dim rng As Range
  Set rng = ActiveDocument.Content
  With rng.Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .Text = SearchText
    With .Font
      .Bold = Bold
      .Italic = Italic
    End With
    .Replacement.ClearFormatting
    .Replacement.style = NewStyle
    .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
  End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Tymothy. Thanks for your answer. I tested your code with a test document of one page to replace style for 9 words and took 0.19 seconds. Then, I tested with the actual file of 8 MB and 1200 pages and more than 10 minutes and is stuck. I don't know if is replacing styles or not since I need to stop the macro and MS word restarts.

Comment: Stop and think it through. You’re doing 546 find and replace operations on a very large document. It isn’t going to be a quick operation. For a comparison, time a find and replace for one word & formatting combination using the standard Word interface.

Comment: Thanks. I'll leave it that way.